# Let $G=\Bbb Z_{30} \times \mathbb Z_{36}$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

Let $G=\Bbb Z_{30}\times \mathbb Z_{36}$.

Divide G to direct product of cyclic gropus from order exponent of prime. Than find all the fairs of generators of G.

I thought about $36\times30=1080=2^3\times3^3\times5$.

Comment: Use `$\Bbb Z_{30}$` for $\Bbb Z_{30}$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

$$\Bbb{Z}_{mn}\cong\Bbb{Z}_m\times\Bbb{Z}_n\iff\gcd(m,n)=1$$

---

*You have managed to write $$\Bbb Z_{30}\times\Bbb Z_{36}\cong\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_3\times\Bbb Z_5\times\Bbb Z_{4}\times\Bbb Z_{9}\tag{1}$$ Let's try to find the number of generators in easier cases. If we look at the group $\Bbb Z_3\times \Bbb Z_9$, we observe that no single element $(a,b)$ can generate it, since there are $3\cdot 9=27$ elements, and $9(a,b)=(0,0)$ (the highest order of any element is $9$, so we can make atmost $9$ different elements with $(a,b)$). This happens because $3\mid 9$.*

*On the other hand $\Bbb Z_3\times\Bbb Z_8$ can be generated by a single element, for instance $(1,1)$ or $(2,3)$,... Which can easily be verified since $\Bbb Z_{24}\cong\Bbb Z_3\times\Bbb Z_8$. This may suggest that $(1)$ requires two generators.*

*Let's denote this generators $$\begin{align}\alpha=(a,b,c,0,0)\\\beta=(0,0,0,d,e)\end{align}$$ How many possibilities are there for $a,b,c,d,e$?*

**Hint:**

> How many generators does $\Bbb Z_n$ have? $$$$ *Let us suppose that $a$ is a generator of $\Bbb Z_n$, then $$a,2a,3a,\dots,na$$ are all distinct elements, in particular $na\equiv_n0$ and $ka\not\equiv_n0$ for $k=1,2,\dots,n-1$. This is the same as saying that the only way to have $n\mid ka$ is to have $n\mid k$. This is precisely the case when $\gcd(a,n)=1$, that is, $a$ generates $\Bbb Z_n$ when $a$ and $n$ have no common factor. The generators of $\Bbb Z_{10}$* for instance is $\{1,3,7,9\}$.

Comment: I know this but in this case $gcd(30,36)\ne1$

Comment: @user579852 That's right, but what if you first look at only $\mathbb{Z}_{30}$. Can you write $\mathbb{Z}_{30}\cong\mathbb{Z}_m\times\mathbb{Z}_n$?

Comment: you mean that $\Bbb Z_{30} \times Z_{36}\cong Z_{3} \times Z_{10} \times Z_{9} \times Z_{4}$? but then how I find all the fairs of generators of G.

Comment: @user579852 Yes! Now, can you expand your product further?

Comment: yes sure to:  $ (Z_{3})^3 \times (Z_{2})^3 \times Z_{5}$. what next?

Comment: Be careful, remember that $\Bbb Z_{9}\not\cong\Bbb Z_{3}\times \Bbb Z_{3}$, since $\gcd(3,3)\neq 1$.

Comment: right so $\Bbb Z_{30}\times \mathbb Z_{36}\cong \mathbb Z_{3}\times \mathbb Z_{9}\times \mathbb Z_{2} \times \mathbb Z_{5}\times \mathbb Z_{4}$, what is next? how do I find all the fairs of generators of G?

Comment: @user579852 Notice that **any** generator $(a,b,c)$, where $a,b,c\neq 0$ generates $\Bbb Z_{2}\times \Bbb Z_{3}\times \Bbb Z_{5}$. This is because all $2,3,5$ are relatively prime. What are the generators of say $\Bbb Z_{3}\times \Bbb Z_{9}$? See if you can spot a pattern :)

Comment: @user579852 For example, can $(1,3)$ generate $\Bbb Z_{3}\times\Bbb Z_{9}$? What about $(1,6)$?

Comment: both of them can't be genertors because $gcd(3,9)\ne1$ and $gcd(6,9)\ne1$, right?

Comment: @user579852 Exactly!

Comment: so I get that: $a=1, b=1,2, c=1,2,3,4, d=1,3, e=1,2,4,5,7,8$, right?

Comment: @user579852 Well done! Now you have found all the generators, so in total there are $1\cdot 2\cdot 4\cdot 2\cdot 6=96$ possible pairs of generators.